Name of the behavior where kids change the rules so they can win
(I was about to ask this on the English Stack Exchange site as a word request, then thought perhaps it is more suitable here. Apologies if it is not).
There is a behavior observed in (I believe mostly) pre-school children whereby, when playing a game with someone (usually someone older), they will change the rules as they go, so that they can win.
Is there a name for this specific behavior?
